# Is there a way in dart to mark methods, that the debugger doesn't step in?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  @debuggerSkip
  Future<void> tapVisible(Finder finder) async {
    await makeVisibleAndPump(finder);
    await tap(finder);
    await pumpAndSettleLowTimeout();
  }
```

Is there a way in dart to mark methods, the debugger should not step into?

Comment: It's a strange question :) the code is executed if it has to be, so the debugger will pass through every part of your code. You just don't have to put breakpoints :)

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There's no feature in the dart; not yet at least. The only way to skip the particular code is to step-over and step-out.